# Will modules make template compilation faster?

Tags: c++, c++11

Will modules make template compilation faster? Templates (usually) have to be header only, and end up residing in the translation unit of the #includer.

Related: Do precompiled headers make template compilation faster?

Comment: What's a module, in C++ terms?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3347.pdf

Answer (score 13):

According to modules proposal, from the very paper you cited, it's the first of the three primary goals for adding modules:

> **1 Introduction**
>
> Modules are a mechanism to package libraries and encapsulate their implementations. 
>   They differ from the traditional approach of translation units and header ﬁles primarily in 
>   that all entities are deﬁned in just one place (even classes, templates, etc.). This paper 
>   proposes a module mechanism (somewhat similar to that of Modula-2) with three 
>   primary goals:
>
> - Signiﬁcantly improve build times of large projects
> - Enable a better separation between interface and implementation
> - Provide a viable transition path for existing libraries
>     While these are the driving goals, the proposal also resolves a number of other longstanding practical C++ issues (initialization ordering, run-time performance, etc.).

So, how can they accomplish those goals? Well, from section 4.1:

> Since header ﬁles are typically included in many other ﬁles, the 
>   growth in build cycles is generally superlinear with respect to the total amount of source 
>   code. If the issue is not addressed, it is likely to become worse as the use of templates 
>   increases and more powerful declarative facilities (like concepts, contract programming, 
>   etc.) are added to the language.
>
> Modules address this issue by replacing the textual inclusion mechanism (whose 
>   processing time is roughly proportional to the amount of code included) by a precompiled 
>   module attachment mechanism (whose processing time—when properly implemented—
>   is roughly proportional to the number of imported declarations).  The property that client 
>   translation units need not be recompiled when private module deﬁnitions change can be 
>   retained.

In other words, at the very least, the time taken to parse these templates is only done once instead of N times, which is already a huge improvement.

Later sections describe improvements for things like explicit instantiation. The one thing this doesn't directly improve is automatic template instantiation, as section 5.8 acknowledges. Here all that can be guaranteed is exactly the same benefit you already get from precompiled headers: "Both modules Set and Reset must instantiate Lib::S and in fact both expose this instantiation in their interface file." But the proposal then gives some possible technical solutions to the ODR problems, at least some of which also solve the multiple-instantiation problem and may not be possible in today's world. For example, the kind of queried instantiation suggested has been tried repeatedly and it's generally considered too hard to get right with today's model, but modules might make it feasible. There's no proof that it's impossible to get right today, just experience that it's hard, and there's no proof that it would be easier with modules, just the plausible possibility that it might be.

And that fits with a general implication that's never quite stated in the proposal, but is there in the background: Making compilation simpler means we might get new optimizations in the process (directly, because it's easier to reason about what's happening, or indirectly, because more people work on the problem once it's not such a huge pain).

In summary, modules can and will definitely make template compilation faster, if for no other reason than that the template definitions themselves only have to be parsed once. They may allow for other benefits that are either impossible or more difficult to do without modules, but that may not be guaranteeable.

Comment: I don't think I'm the only one that would think that does *not* say it will improve the build time of templates. It says entities (including templates) are defined in 1 place, and that Modules will significantly improve build times. I'm not inferring anything else than that from it. _How_ can they improve template build times is what I should have asked.

Comment: Well, you could read the rest of the document. I'll edit my answer to add one sample quote.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, but it is possible to export a template class from modules, without specifying exported types. I.e vector, algorithms and everything in the SDL can be exported as modules?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about modules, but I do know that gcc even now provides precompiled headers, as do many other compilers. A precompiled header can contain a very efficient machine-readable version of a template description, so when that is available upon inclusion of a header, many compiling steps can be skipped which would normally be required for a source-text-only uncompiled header.

The modules paper talks about precompiled interface files, so I assume that current precompiled headers and new precompiled interface files will provide comparable peformance. Creating such a file from a plain text portable module description will probably be more efficient as it can save time due to restrictions of the language syntax. And it will be more standardized, so more headers will get the benefit of precompilation. Current projects seldom precompile more than one header, and cross-project precompiled headers are even rarer in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

> Do precompiled headers make template compilation faster?

No; it makes templates *not compile*. Which is the entire point of both PCHs and modules: to stop compiling everything.

The idea is to turn "load C++ text and compile" into "load C++ symbols." Modules are a generalized form of PCHs.

Now, you still have the cost of *instantiating* templates (unless they were instantiated within a PCH/module). But the cost of compiling the C++ template code is removed.

Comment: I though "compile" included template instantiation.  I'm... kinda sure it does.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Compilation and instantiation aren't the same thing. Compilation goes from C++ text to an internal memory representation. Instantiation goes from an internal memory representation to actual C++ symbols (functions and objects with names) and implementations.

Comment: According to the C++ spec, Compilation starts with mapping physical source file characters to the basic character set, and ends with linking with external references.  So yes, template instantiation is totally part of compilation.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Of course, PCHs and modules aren't standard either. So it's rather hard to talk about it in terms of standardized language.

Comment: I'm sure whatever happens with PCHs and modules, they will be part of compilation too, since the _entire process from text to executable is compilation_.